# Problems With MapBox Installation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapbox

I am trying to install MapBox SDK on Xcode Version 10.1

What I have done so far is:
Created the pod file

```
pod 'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.29.0'
```

I then set the `MGLMapboxAccessToken`and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to the correct credentials as specified in the documentation

I then updated the “Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture” and “Location updates” to be enabled

I imported the librabries

```
import MapboxDirections
import MapboxCoreNavigation
import MapboxNavigation
```

I then added this code to make a route

```
let origin = Waypoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.9131752, longitude: -77.0324047), name: "Mapbox")
let destination = Waypoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.8977, longitude: -77.0365), name: "White House")

let options = NavigationRouteOptions(waypoints: [origin, destination])

Directions.shared.calculate(options) { (waypoints, routes, error) in
    guard let route = routes?.first else { return }

    let viewController = NavigationViewController(for: route)
    present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

My problem is that there are a lot of errors and warning on the side is there anything I can do to get rid of them?

[image]

I tried changing code to recommended settings using 'fix' but its only caused more errors

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can silence warnings from pods with this line in your `Podfile`. Unfortunately not all third parties are releasing warning-free pods so unless you want to dig into each and every warning, tweak the source, etc., you may need to go this route to get a clean build.

```
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By any chance do you know how I can make MapBox run faster? I am very new to this!

Comment: Glad I could help. That really depends on what you're doing, how much data you have, where it's coming from, how your code is written, and many other factors.  Try using it and once you've got a specific case where you need it to be faster, please post a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with specific code examples, etc. and someone will be sure to try and answer.